# VB6 Finding a combobox listindex based off of a specific string

Tags: combobox, vb6, listbox

I have a combobox with many items on the list. I just need to find the index of a specific string and have the combobox change to that index. I have a query that returns a result as string.

```
 Function FindComboIndex(cmbDealerName,result)

 For int i = 0 to cmbDealerName.ListItems.Count

 If result = cmbdealername.ListItem(i).Text Then

 cmbdealername.listindex = i

 End if

 Next i

 End function
```

Something like this, i just need the right syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
Sub FindComboIndex(ByVal cmbDealerName As ComboBox, ByVal result As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To cmbDealerName.ListCount - 1
        If result = cmbDealerName.List(i) Then
            cmbDealerName.ListIndex = i
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT: fixing code since it wasn't tested and did not work. Code above now works

Comment: Added an `Exit Sub` if the string is found so it doesn't keep looping.